# How to use Loader and StackView both together, when needs some pages load once and some several times?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a pages flow like this:

[image]

That i Implemented it with a "Loader" and a "StackView", "splash" and "authorize" load in "Loader", and "Dashboard" and other pages will load in "StackView", "StackView" is not nasted (load) in "Loader", Just i invisable it befor load "Dashboard" like:

```
Loader {
    id:loader
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: true // till authorization
    source: "qrc:/pages/Splash.qml"
}
StackView {
    id: stack_view
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: false // till authorization done and load dashboard
}
StateGroup {
    id: state_group
    state: "SPLASH"
    states: [
        State {
            name: "SPLASH"
            PropertyChanges {target: loader; source: "qrc:/pages/Splash.qml"}
        },
        State {
            name: "AOUTHORIZE"
            PropertyChanges {target: loader; source: "qrc:/pages/Login.qml"}
        },
        State {
            name: "STACKVIEW"
            PropertyChanges {target: loader; visible: false}
            PropertyChanges {target: stack_view; visible: true}
        }
    ]
}
```

As diagram shows "Splash" and "Authorize" load once, "Dashboard" and other pages may load several times, I want to know the way i used "Loader" and "StackView" is good? or how and what components is beter to use?

Comment: Please read the [Item Ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#item-ownership) notes: _any item pushed onto a StackView will never be destroyed by the StackView; only items that StackView creates from Components or URLs are destroyed by the StackView_. So if you created a page instance it will never be deleted and can be reused.

Comment: @folibis Yes, I'm Using 'qrc:/pages/page.qml' to push pages in StackView But somthings was wierd! That If i  just use a StackView the first push (here 'qrc:/pages/splash.qml') will not destroy and i had to care pop StackView to splash(if i pop dashboard, splash will shown)! So I think i had to use Loader or somthing...

Comment: Why don't you use the `StackView` for all items?

Comment: @m7913d I prefer stack_view.pop(null) return to Dashboard, Also I have some common signals in Pages and connections on stack_view.currentItem, But i will if it be the better way